# Share bookmark for both Safari and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, safari, bookmarks

I have a Mac with both Safari and Firefox as my primary browsers. I like to use both. Is there any way to share my Firefox bookmarks with my Safari? I guess one way is to change my browser configuration settings to let both to point to the same bookmark file. However, I am not sure if the bookmark for Safari will be compatible with the one of Firefox?

Another way might be to export or import bookmark from one to another one. Not sure if this can be done by script?

Answer (score 3):

Go for Xmarks. It syncs between Safari, Firefox, Internet Explorer and across the platforms (Mac, PC). That way *all* your bookmarks are in sync if you wish to do so.
You can define profiles (i.e. to keep work and private apart) and if xmarks is not available ( think internet cafe) you could use your bookmarks directly from the Xmarks webpage after logging in.

I'm a sucker when it comes to new services running in the background (the less, the better) and I'm happy with Xmarks in this respect as well. Can only recommend it.

Comment: I recommend Xmarks as well.  I use it between multiple Mac and PC computers, and it has always worked flawlessly.  They even recently added support for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give [AllBookmarks](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/AllBookmarks) a try. It supports sharing bookmarks among different browsers and can be downloaded for free.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you're asking for, but I use [Google Bookmarks](http://google.com/bookmarks) for this purpose.  It is not as convenient as something built-in, but it's very portable and works well for me.

Comment: I do use Google Bookmarks, however I prefer to use local bookmark with Xmarks (previous called as foxMark) addin to sync my bookmark in Firefox.

Comment: I also use Google bookmarks, and find it useful as a sync option between browsers. The only possible downside is that each browser needs a Google toolbar, and you need to be logged in continually, which personally I don't mind.

Comment: You don't need the Google Toolbar if you use the website.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to drop bookmarks altogether and use [Delicious](http://delicious.com/) tagging instead. I find tagging much more intuitive and useful than bookmarks stored in a purely hierarchical structure.

There are addons for both [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615) and [Safari](http://delicioussafari.com/) that will make your interaction with Delicious more streamlined.

Comment: I use the favorite tags view in Delicious as my bookmarks toolbar on every machine I own.  This gives me consistent bookmarks from machine to machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the focus of your bookmarks to the web, you can share them across any web browser. Free services like [BookmarkSync](http://bookmarksync.com/) allow you to do this. With the advantage that bookmarks stay in your browsers.

The concept is loosely based on [Social Bookmarking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_bookmarking). However here there is a very private component which you may appreciate (I certainly do).